# How to find the minimum sum of unknown variables that is a solution to a system of two linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying find the minimum sum of $x_{1} + x_{2} + ... + x_{n}$ where these are a solution to a linear system of two equations.

System of linear equations in general form:
$$
        a_{11}x_{1} + a_{12}x_{2} + ... a1_{n}x_{n} = b_{1} \\
        a_{21}x_{1} + a_{22}x_{2} + ... a2_{n}x_{n} = b_{2}
$$
The unknown variables $(x_{i})$ and coefficients $(a_{ji})$ are non-negative whole numbers, i.e:

$$
x_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0} \\
a_{ij}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}
$$
As for the constant terms $(b_{j})$, they are positive whole numbers, i.e:
$$
b_{j}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\gt0}
$$

The number of unknown variables may be any positive number $(n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\gt0})$. 
Since each unknown variable is non-negative, there are a *finite* number of solutions, which may be zero in the case the system is not solvable.

Example:
$$
10x_{1} + 5x_{2} + 0x_{3} = 10 \\
2x_{1} + 0x_{2} + 1x_{3} = 2 
$$
The only two solutions are
$$
1: x_{1} = 1, x_{2} = 0, x_{3} = 0 \\
2: x_{1} = 0, x_{2} = 2, x_{3} = 2
$$
where the sum of $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}$ in the first solution is $1$, and $2$ in the second, making the first solution the answer.

---

How do I find the minimum sum of $x_{1} + x_{2} + ... + x_{n}$ that satisfy two equations with the constraints above? Solution sets are a challenge to describe when using so many unknown variables, is there a better way to solve my question? Can Matrix multiplication with Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse be used? 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can write your equation as $$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\dots a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\dots a_{2n}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{bmatrix}$$

In which case you know that in the reals, you have infinitely many or zero solutions. Using the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse will yield the smallest (by norm) solution to the system, but it will in general not be positive and will not be all integer.

Comment: @5xum if I understand correctly, the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse will disregard that the unknown variables must be non-negative?

Comment: Yes, and also, it will return the solution with the smallest $2$ norm, not the smallest sum (which, for positive vectors, is a $1$ norm). So the norm of $(1,1)$ is $\sqrt{2}$, not $2$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is what's called an integer linear program (ILP), you can read about it online. In general, ILP is very hard to solve (NP-hard, to be exact) although certain cases have fast solutions. Unfortunately yours is not one of those easy cases. Just to find a solution $x$ for one of the equations, (let alone the one with minimal sum), you have to find an integer combination of the $a_{ij}$ that add up to $b_i$. This is a variation of the "subset sum" problem and also "knapsack problem," known to be NP-complete.

If you read about the knapsack problem, you will see that you can use "dynamic programming" to solve it reasonably fast if the $a_{ij}$ and $b_j$ are not too large. In your case you have two equations instead of one, but you can still take a dynamic programming approach.

NOTE: You can also use a standard ILP solver, which may work faster because they usually have a lot of heurisitics (although still guaranteed to find an optimal solution). Cplex is a commercial LP and ILP solver (although I think the free versions have limits on how many variales you can have). If nothing else, you can code your own branch-and-bound ILP solver if you don't find one online to suit your needs. (Branch-and-bound ILP solving is easy to read about online.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, dynamic programming seems like a good start since $a_{ij}$ and $b{j}$ are relatively small in my problem. I will try it out and see how it goes :)

Comment: @Marcus Nice. It's unfortunate you have two equations instead of one, because having two equations will increase the complexity of your dynamic programming. But I still think that if you have many variables, the DP can be better than generic ILP solvers. I forgot to mention you can use an ILP solver such as Cplex, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Cheers, your answer has given me quite a lot of options so I will mark it as the answer to my solution, thanks again!